Do we use the verb "eat" or "cry" alone to express sudden actions?
Does it sound right to say "The man was talking to the woman when she cried" and "Suddenly, out of nowhere, a big fish ate my finger"?
I guess "cry" and "eat" are verbs express long actions and can not be used for sudden actions.
So, "The man was talking to the woman when she started to cry" and "Suddenly, out of nowhere, a big fish bit my finger" sound better.
Is that correct?

Yes, you are correct. A common way of saying that someone suddenly started to cry is "she burst into tears".

Yes, we eat fish fingers but fish (occasionally) bite ours.

Why do you suppose eating can't be sudden? It takes a fraction of a second for an animal to put something in its mouth and swallow it. This sentence as written implies the fish quickly swallowed your finger, I see nothing wrong with it. "Biting" simply isn't the same action as "eating", it describes more an action with the teeth than swallowing. You can bite something without eating it or, eat it without biting it. You probably wouldn't say you suddenly ate a 12-course meal, but a frog can surely eat a fly suddenly.

The example of a fish eating a finger is too unusual to be usefully analyzed, because fish don't typically eat fingers, suddenly or otherwise.  But if you changed the context to a more common one, the use of suddenly eat would appear natural: "I looked away for a second and suddenly the dog ate the meat right off of my plate."

Nb, "cry" can have a short-action meaning, to exclaim. But this is usually used as "cried out," or with mention of what was said ("Bill cried 'Stop!'").

1,2 345. once I caught a fish alive....

don't bite a finger and eat a finger exist in Vietnamese? This is not about English. What is a long action. by the way.

...6, 7, 8, 9, 10  then I let it go again. Why did you let it go? Because it bit my finger so. Which finger did it bite?  This little finger on my right. (The end)

In which universe would a fish appear out of nowhere and actually eat someone's finger while they were conversing, presumably on dry land, with someone? Sometimes you create the most bizarre situations! Yes, bite/bit works better but this scenario would be set on a boat or by a lake/river

There's nothing wrong with the fish sentence grammatically, but it doesn't mean the same thing as your correction. If a fish suddenly eats your finger, it has swallowed it in a single bite and you have lost a finger. If a fish suddenly bites your finger, you might be in pain, but you probably still have a finger.
For the other sentence, yes, "when she cried" would never be interpreted as suddenly starting to shed tears. It could be an unusual way of saying that she suddenly shouted something, but that is a different meaning of the word.
